# Decoupling GUI from a parsing engine

Tags: c++, parsing, user-interface, architecture

I am writing a parser for a hugely complex internal file format - for training purposes. I need to implement some sort of DSL for parsing - and then display the sections of format in a GUI, as some sort of a tree view. I want to be able to have the parsing engine in one process and the UI in another. So for example I want the UI to ask the parser engine to parse a file. The parser then returns some sort of tree containing sections and fields in the tree, and the GUI then displays it.

How do I make them communicate? (The language is C++). Do I make the engine a DLL and export the needed functions or how else to implement this. I cannot use external libraries.

Comment: What about Model–view–controller pattern?

Comment: @PetarPetrov not what i'm looking for. I want to completely decouple the engine from the UI, not just delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big problem. The interaction is one way, that helps a lot. Define an output format for the parser/input format for the UK, before writing either. If the format is well defined, you can even have two developers write the two parts independently.